# Background images path in Sass and Compass

Tags: css, ruby, compass-sass, sass

This is mentioned in config.rb file

```
images_dir = "images"
```

I use 2 folder for images in my projects inside images folder

```
images
images/background/
images/content/
```

**If any images is inside `images/background/` folder then how i should add the path for image in css `background` and  Sass variables?**

```
$header-img: "sass.gif";
```

and

```
background-image: url('sass.gif?1327592426');
```

**And how to get rid of this auto generated `?1327592426` from each background image?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use the `image-url` [URL helper](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/). It "generates a path to an asset found relative to the project's images directory" which you defined in your `config.rb`. You can also set the third parameter `$cache-buster` to false to remove the generated `?1327592426`

Sass:

```
// image-url arguments:
// $path: path relative to images directory in config.rb
// $path-only: if true, will cause only the path to be returned instead of a `url()` function
// $cache-buster: When set to `false` no cache buster will be used (i.e. `?313420982`)
$header-img: image-url('background/sass.gif', false, false)
background-image: $header-img
```

Generated CSS:

```
background-image: url('images/background/sass.gif')
```

Comment: if i use `$header-img: image-url('background/sass.gif', false, true)` it gives `background-image: url('/images/url('/images/background/sass.gif')');`

Comment: Just updated answer to be clearer about using $header-img. If you want to define `background-image` in your Sass using `url()`, set the second argument to `true`. Then, you would write `background-image: url($header-img)` in Sass

Comment: @JitendraVyas if you don't want the forward slash '/' at the beginning of the image-path, put this line in the `config.rb`-file: `relative_assets = true`

Comment: @JitendraVyas to set the $cache-buster to false by default, put this line in your config.rb `asset_cache_buster :none`

Comment: Also worth having a look at the [different configuration references](http://beta.compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) of compass, specifically `images_dir`.