# Sass background images

Tags: css, image, background, sass

I have been to this page: [Background images path in Sass and Compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021306/background-images-path-in-sass-and-compass)  and it seems like it should be the answer to my question, but I am missing something. Here is my code:

config.rb

```
images_dir = 'img'
```

sass file

```
header { background: image-url('raeshineLogo.png', false, false); }
```

which outputs to:

```
  header {
  background: url('/img/raeshineLogo.png');
  }
```

Seems like it should work, the path is correct, but what am I missing?

Comment: If th URL starts with a / (for instance, `url(/img/...`), the path is absolute, and not relative. This means the img folder is being looked up on the sites root directory, and not in the (let's say) css/img directory.

Comment: Is there a way to make it stop outputting that / ? I saw this in the page that is linked above: `relative_assets = true` but I am not having any luck.

Comment: The path is raeshine/img, where raeshine is the root directory. In the config.rb file, I have: `css_dir = 'css'`, and that one works. The JS folder is also ok, so I'm very confused why the img folder is not found in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Solved! As I thought, it was a silly mistake. But it turned out to have nothing to do with the path.

If anyone happens upon this page with a similar issue, see link above to the other Stack Overflow question, and this page: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/  (part of maxbeatty's answer).