# Angular CLI webpack public path is not being updated

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

I'm working with angular cli and webpack. I have a code to change the variable **webpack_require**.p in runtime but when the application compile scss files is not using the new value of **webpack_require**.p and an image in css is not loading.

This work just fine with the angular cli version 1.6.7 but now I'm using version 1.7.2 and is not working: below is my code:

```
declare var __webpack_require__: any;

__webpack_require__.p = newValue;
```

My scss file looks like this:

```
.className {
background: url(../../../dir1/dir2/images/imageName.jpg) no-repeat; }
```

UPDATE:
Using CLI version 1.7.3 doesn't fix the problem. Others resources work just fine but not the scss background url image.

Comment: Can you check if the webpack dependency version change between the two angular-cli versions?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes, it changed from 3.10 to 3.11

Comment: @Jack1987, why not just create loader to change public path? what are trying to achieve?

Comment: @OkanAslankan Are you sure Angular CLI 1.7.xx uses Webpack 4? I can only see webpack 4 in some pre-release [v6.0.0-beta.4](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases).

Comment: @cyberpirate92 oops. yes I check it now. removing comment to people not follow that path.

Comment: Im curious, what happens when you put the background-image url into a string? like `url('link/to/your/file.jpg')`?

Comment: Did you check this answer? Might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030273/5358917

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030273/5358917 doesn't solve the problem